# React component vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, npm

I have been working as a Junior Dev for almost 1 year and I am now moving in a bit more serious stuff.

I have built an app with React for my company and recently I have been looking at the various sub-dependencies of `react-scripts` and found out that, although NPM does not flag them when executing `npm audit` two components are **highly** vulnerable.

`dot-prop 4.2.0` and `open 6.4.0`

I've been looking around for ways to update them but they cannot be update because of caret versioning (they are sub-dependencies).

My question is: 
If I never `require` those components, is my app at risk?
When executing `npm run build` are they in any way included in the final code?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you consider those packages vulnerable if they aren't flagged by `npm audit`? Where did you see that they were vulnerable and what are the vulnerabilities?

Comment: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-8116   dot-prop any version before 5.2.0